# aws-sdk, How to send JSONArray to DynamoDB updateItem() method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am unable to send JsonArray to SetExpressionAttributeValues() of UpdateItemRequest to be able to pass to DynamoDBClient.updateItem() method

Following is the JsonArray ,which i want to pass to SetExpressionAttributeValues() Method of updateItemRequest.

```
[{"ID":"T1","Result":1},{"ID":"T2","Result":0}]
```

How can i do it?

I tried using following way,

```
UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest();
updateItemRequest.setTableName(DYNAMODB_TABLE);
updateItemRequest.withKey(keyMap);  

Map attributeNameData = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
attributeNameData.put("#c",new AttributeValue().withS("list1"));
updateItemRequest.withExpressionAttributeNames(attributeNameData);
updateItemRequest.withUpdateExpression("SET #c = list_append(#c, :vals)");

Map expressionAttributeValue = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
expressionAttributeValue.put(":vals",new AttributeValue().withS(jsonOutput));
updateItemRequest.setExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValue);
```

But its giving error as ,

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to marshall request to JSON: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
```

I am new to Amazon Dynamo DB and i am using AWS Mobile SDK, But could not find anything useful in AWS Documentation, can anybody help me?

Thanks In advance!